# how to avoid getting a running a red light fine when making rights on red on ats?

Tags: american-truck-simulator

It seems that making rights on reds is okay; perhaps my assumption is incorrect.

Sometimes I get fined sometimes I don't - so I'm really not quite sure.

How can I make a right on red w/o getting fined?

Comment: I know in real life, there are signs saying (in America) "No Turn on Red" or "No Right On Red".  Maybe see if those signs are there?

Comment: Are you using your turn signal every time? You may also need to come to a complete stop.